# Create an empty QStringList directly in a QML file

Tags: qt, qml

I hope someone can help me with this. I have an external QML Module which accepts a QStringList as parameter. However, what I have is a simple String. My question is: Is there a way in QML to convert a list of Strings into a QStringList without any external c++ functions?
Thanks

I tried to pass a simple string but it is not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript array of strings or `list<string>` depending on your Qt version. Have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-list.html).

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property var jsArray: ["apple", "banana", "mango"]
    property list<string> stringList: ["Oslo", "Berlin", "New York"]

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var arr = ["more", "strings", "here"]

        applicationData.setSomething(arr)
        applicationData.setSomething(root.stringList)
        applicationData.setSomething(root.jsArray)
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>

class ApplicationData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void setSomething(const QStringList &list) const
    {
        for (const auto &s : list)
            qDebug() << s;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;

    ApplicationData data;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationData", &data);
    view.setSource(QUrl(u"qrc:/75085103/main.qml"_qs));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```